# Show that $A$ is invertible if and only if all the singular values of $A$ are non-zero where $A$ is a square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, singular-values

$\Longrightarrow$
Assume $A$ is invertible. not sure how to do then

$\Longleftarrow$
Assume all the singular values of $A$ are non-zero.

There exists two orthogonal matrices
$U \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, V \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}, \Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m} \ s.t. \ \Sigma_{1,1} \geq \Sigma_{2,2} \geq ... \geq 0$ such that $A = U\Sigma V^\top$, and $U$ and $V$ are invertible

Since the diagonal of $\Sigma$ is non-zero, $\Sigma$ is invertible $\Rightarrow$ $A=U\Sigma V^\top$ is invertible

Also if now we assume A is invertible. How to show that
$$\sigma_1(A)\sigma_1(A^{−1}) \geq 1$$
where $\sigma_1(A)$ and $\sigma_1(A^{−1})$ represents the largest singular value of $A$ and $A^{-1}$.

Comment: Once you know that $A=U\Sigma V^\top$ then $A$ inversible implies $U^{-1}A(V^\top)^{-1}$ inversible and $\Sigma$ inversible implies $U\Sigma V^\top$ inversible. The largest singular value of $A^{-1}$ is the inverse of the least singular value of $A$.

Comment: another approach is to notice that $\Big \vert\det\big(A\big)\Big \vert = \prod_{k=1}^n \sigma_k$